# how does (PyTorch) model.load_state_dict() work for modified model?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, resnet

I've modified BasicBlock of Resnet architecture by adding a few more FC layers at the end of the block.
I tried model.load_state_dict() on the new model and it worked perfectly.
I wonder how the weights of these layers are treated when I load pretrained weights.
Are pretrained weights assigned properly to correct layers and weights from new layers are intialized randomly?
Or model.load_state_dict() fail in this scenario and all weights of the model are intialized from the beginning?

Comment: "model.load_state_dict()" will go over every (key, value) pair from the pre-trained model and compare it with your new model. If the key's match (i.e., the names of the different modules are the same), then "model.load_state_dict()" will match the values between the same keys.

Comment: I understand now, thanks you very much!